# Uniformjs is disabled when an element is cloned

Tags: jquery, uniform

So i'm cloning a div that has several input items in it. The system's libraries automatically applies uniform to all elements even if it is hidden. After cloning and appending an item, the styling is still intact but the input elements are no longer clickable

HTML

```
<div id="ctr-ant" class="hidden">
          <div class="what-ctr">
          <input id="visible_signs[]" name="visible_signs[]" class="visible_signs[]" value="Presence of eggs" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

JS

```
var parentctr  = obj.parents('.pest-container');
var clone = $($('#ctr-ant').html()).clone(true,true);
clone.appendTo(parentctr);
```

The cloning works fine. Except for the unclickable checkboxes.

Also, uniformjs.com is currently inaccessible so I don't know if there's a workaround to this.

Comment: That is to be expected. The plugin's click handlers will not be cloned. You need to post the rest of your code in order to provide an appropriate solution. One solution may be to clone only non-styled elements and reapply the plugin to them.

Comment: Is there a way to unbind the plugin and reapply it? All elements are automatically bound on load by the main framework so I can't really do anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Unbound uniformjs using

```
 $.uniform.restore('input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]');
```

and called

```
$('input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]').uniform();
```

after.